# Search ActiveDirectory using full name in C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

`UserPrincipal`'s `FindByIdentity` method allows me to search ActiveDirectory using username.
However, I also want to be able to search using user's real name (e.g. Wayne, Bruce)

How can I do this?

Comment: Beware, you might end up finding out who Bruce Wayne is...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce"
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

**Update:**

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `Surname` (or last name)
- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: he wanted to search by full name so you need to set the UserPrincipal.Surname = "Wayne"; as well.

Comment: @John P: in the title of the post, it clearly says "first name" .... but you're right - if you want to search by "surname" (last name), you'd need the `.Surname` property instead. You could also search by `DisplayName` (first + last name) or others - the mechanics are the same for each of those.

Comment: It seems you're right, I was going on the example he gave in the text of the question rather than the title.

Comment: +1 for using FindAll and looping as well. A lot of people are surprised when they discover that multiple people can have the same name and their code is crashing or assigning stuff to the wrong person. Been there, done that :)